# Why does adding an "import" to my file cause the "require.config()" call to no longer work?

Tags: typescript, requirejs

In the file where I apply my settings to require.config, I also placed other settings which included importing a view model using typescript's export functionality. I noticed it was producing the error in all browsers:

**requireConfig.ts**

```
import HomePage from "Custom/HomePage";

require.config
({
    baseUrl: "/Scripts/",    
    paths: {},
    shim: {}
});

require (["Custom/Initialisation/ConfigOnDocReady"]);
```

*`Uncaught TypeError: require.config is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (RequireConfig.ts:3)`*

When I remove line 1, it works. What is causing this? I think this is a good opportunity to learn whats behind requireJs' curtain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Summary

RequireJS provides `require` locally and globally. You are calling `config` on a locally provided `require`. A local `require` has no `config` method, and you get the error you get. You should call `config` on the global require. RequireJS exports an alias to the global `require` as `requirejs`, or you could access it as `window.require`.

### The Long Explanation

#### RequireJS's local and global `require` calls

RequireJS provides two points of access to `require`: a global one, and a local one. In the browser, the global one is exported into the global space, `window`. The local `require` is provided if you specifically request it as a module in your dependency list when you call `define`. Calling `define` is the standard way to register an AMD module with an AMD loader (which is what RequireJS is). The argument to the callback here is a local `require`:

```
define(['require'], function (require) {
});
```

(It is also automatically provided to the callback if you entirely omit the dependency list, but this scenario needs not detain us here.)

The local `require` does not provide a `config` method. It wouldn't make much sense if it did because calling `config` has global effects. For instance, there's no provision for changing `baseUrl` only for some modules in a context but not others. So RequireJS provides a `config` method only on the global `require`.

"But wait", you say, "I'm not calling `define` anywhere!"

No, but TypeScript is emitting code that calls `define`.

#### How TypeScript emits your code

Your code works when you remove the `import` because TypeScript outputs significantly different code depending on whether it is present:

1. When you have the `import` statement, then your code is wrapped in something *similar* to the `define` I've shown above, and consequently, your call to `require` is a call to the *local* one. (The `define` wrapper produced by `tsc` is more complex, but that's not important here.)
2. If there are no `import/export` statements, the code is considered to be a "script" and TypeScript won't output any module-related code. In particular, the code emitted won't have a `define` wrapper as I've shown above, and your call to `require` is a call to the *global* one.

#### The Upshot

If you want to change configuration from inside a module, you should take care of calling the global `require`. RequireJS exports it also under the `requirejs` alias. So you can call `requirejs.config`. Or you can access it explicitly through `window` as `window.require`.